# how to get past on the if statement when check for values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with comparing the variables on the if statement.

I want to comparing on the variable `start_time` with the current time to see if it is equal with the current time and I want to comparing on the variables `start_time` and `stop_time` with the current time to see if the current program is half way through or if the current program has ended.

Example: the current time show as `01:20` and I check the variable `start_date` which it show as `01:15`. I want to check if it equal with the current time and print `the program has started`. When my current time show as `01:35`, I want to check with the variable `start_date` which it show `01:20` and I want to check with the variable `stop_date` which it show as `02:15` so i want to print `the program is half way through`. If the current time is greater than `02:15` then I want to print `the program has ended`.

Here is what I am using:

```
if current_time == start_time:
    print "program started"

elif current_time <= stop_time:
    print "program finished"


elif current_time > start_time and stop_time < start_time:
    print "program half way"
```

Here is the full code:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=?', [channels])
stop_date = cur.fetchone()

if stop_date is not None:
    start_date = str(stop_date[0])
    stop_date = str(stop_date[1])
    get_current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    get_start_time = time.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    start_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_start_time)
    get_stop_time = time.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    stop_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_stop_time)
    current_time = str(get_current_time)


    if current_time == start_time:
        print "program started"

    elif current_time <= stop_time:
        print "program finished"


    elif current_time > start_time and stop_time < start_time:
        print "program half way"
```

Here is the `start_date` data:

```
14:18:45 T:4976  NOTICE: 01:15
14:18:45 T:4976  NOTICE: 01:20
14:18:45 T:4976  NOTICE: 00:40
14:18:45 T:4976  NOTICE: 00:10
14:18:46 T:4976  NOTICE: 23:55
14:18:46 T:4976  NOTICE: 01:10
14:18:46 T:4976  NOTICE: 01:50
```

Here is the `stop_date` data:

```
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 02:15
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 03:20
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 02:30
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 02:10
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 01:55
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 02:05
14:21:12 T:4712  NOTICE: 02:40
```

Here is the current time:
    2016-01-01 14:13:30.707000

When I try to comparing using this line `elif current_time > start_time and stop_time < start_time`, it won't let me to check between the current time, `start_date` and `stop_date`.

Can you please show me an example of how I could comparing the variables `start_date` and `stop_date` with the current time to see if the program has started, got half way through of if the current program has ended?

Comment: I can see current_time is a string while start_date and stop_date are time objects, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to convert the datetime objects to string, you can compare them directly, like in this example:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = "2016-01-01 14:18:45"
stop_date = "2016-01-01 18:21:12"

current_datetime = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
stop_datetime = datetime.strptime(stop_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


if current_datetime == start_datetime:
    print "program started"
elif start_datetime < current_datetime < stop_datetime:
    print "program half way"
else:
    print "program finished"
```

Comment: thank you for this, what do you mean by what exactly are the values? do you mean what type?

Comment: Yes, the types seem wrong. You don't need to convert the values returned by `time.strptime()` and `datetime.datetime.now()` to strngs, you can compare the directly.

Comment: Ok do you know how I can compare them directly when checking with the variables and the current time to see if the program is started, half way through or if the program has ended?